# How to put drawable above/bellow layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm using constraint layout and popup window to put my bitmap image below layout.I'm trying to put drawable as a background of layout, but it is not working.

Here is my drawable:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/tutorial_bottom_arrow"
    android:gravity="bottom|left">
    </bitmap>
```

Here is my xml layout :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/popup_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/tutorial_arrow_up"
    >
```

I need something like this :
[Image above layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVhbx.png)

Comment: you can make it using frame layout easily

Comment: @VivekMishra Thanks, but don't know how to put it bellow layout.One half of the picture is inside layout, the other one is bellow it.

Comment: for frame layout you can give it some negative top margin to move it upwards. You can make it using relative layout too by positioning image in center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this you can use custom dialog**

```
Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(this);
myDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dailog_layout);
myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
myDialog.show();
```

**create a custom_dailog_layout file this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rl_dialog_container"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp">

<View
    android:id="@+id/imagePadding"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/round_dialog_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imagePadding"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/imagePadding2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Nilesh"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_image"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot man, but I need to use constraint layout for scaling on different device sizes